# Various linker errors in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker, lnk2019, lnk2001

I'm working on a school assignment for which we given some .lib files. I added them in the linker, and still I'm getting linker errors. When I changed those to a different path, I get a file not found error instead. My errors are:

```
Error   53  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport)    public: __thiscall sql::SQLString::~SQLString(void)" (__imp_??1SQLString@sql@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: static class std::vector<class Address *,class std::allocator<class Address *> > __cdecl AddressDAO::findAddressByCity(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?findAddressByCity@AddressDAO@@SA?AV?$vector@PAVAddress@@V?$allocator@PAVAddress@@@std@@@std@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@3@@Z)    C:\Users\Kenny\Documents\software project\Groep 6\Docs\Dev-Branch-Kenny\KiaDealer\KiaDealer\AddressDAO.obj
Error   54  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sql::SQLString::~SQLString(void)" (__imp_??1SQLString@sql@@QAE@XZ)  C:\Users\Kenny\Documents\software project\Groep 6\Docs\Dev-Branch-Kenny\KiaDealer\KiaDealer\DatabaseSingleton.obj
Error   55  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sql::SQLString::SQLString(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0SQLString@sql@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: static class std::vector<class Address *,class std::allocator<class Address *> > __cdecl AddressDAO::findAddressByCity(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?findAddressByCity@AddressDAO@@SA?AV?$vector@PAVAddress@@V?$allocator@PAVAddress@@@std@@@std@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@3@@Z) C:\Users\Kenny\Documents\software project\Groep 6\Docs\Dev-Branch-Kenny\KiaDealer\KiaDealer\AddressDAO.obj
Error   56  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sql::SQLString::SQLString(char const * const)" (__imp_??0SQLString@sql@@QAE@QBD@Z) referenced in function "public: static class std::vector<class Address *,class std::allocator<class Address *> > __cdecl AddressDAO::findAddressByCity(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?findAddressByCity@AddressDAO@@SA?AV?$vector@PAVAddress@@V?$allocator@PAVAddress@@@std@@@std@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@3@@Z)   C:\Users\Kenny\Documents\software project\Groep 6\Docs\Dev-Branch-Kenny\KiaDealer\KiaDealer\AddressDAO.obj
Error   57  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sql::SQLString::SQLString(char const * const)" (__imp_??0SQLString@sql@@QAE@QBD@Z)  C:\Users\Kenny\Documents\software project\Groep 6\Docs\Dev-Branch-Kenny\KiaDealer\KiaDealer\DatabaseSingleton.obj
Error   58  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sql::SQLString::operator class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &(void)const " (__imp_??BSQLString@sql@@QBEABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "public: static class std::vector<class Address *,class std::allocator<class Address *> > __cdecl AddressDAO::findAddressByCity(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?findAddressByCity@AddressDAO@@SA?AV?$vector@PAVAddress@@V?$allocator@PAVAddress@@@std@@@std@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@3@@Z)    C:\Users\Kenny\Documents\software project\Groep 6\Docs\Dev-Branch-Kenny\KiaDealer\KiaDealer\AddressDAO.obj
Error   59  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__get_driver_instance referenced in function "private: __thiscall DatabaseSingleton::DatabaseSingleton(void)" (??0DatabaseSingleton@@AAE@XZ) C:\Users\Kenny\Documents\software project\Groep 6\Docs\Dev-Branch-Kenny\KiaDealer\KiaDealer\DatabaseSingleton.obj
Error   60  error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Kenny\Documents\software project\Groep 6\Docs\Dev-Branch-Kenny\KiaDealer\Debug\KiaDealer.exe
```

I cannot get it to compile. I've even tried changing the project from unicode to the other options, since I read that that fixed someone's problems with one of these errors.

Edit, I'm also getting a LOT of these warnings, which are probably related:
Warning 1   warning C4251: 'sql::SQLString::realStr' : class 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'sql::SQLString'  c:\users\kenny\documents\software project\groep 6\docs\dev-branch-kenny\kiadealer\kiadealer\include\cppconn\sqlstring.h 38

Comment: The errors state SQL. Maybe you should have SQL in the tags too.

Comment: @G.Samaras: this question has nothing to do with SQL statements or the SQL language. It should not have an [sql] tag.

Comment: Mat I told it because I saw sql in the errors, but I am not sure, that's why I told maybe. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: It mention SQL since it's a database connecting lib

Answer (score 1):

It does compile, but it does not link, there is a difference. After googling this for you, it would seem you are not compiling for the proper platform; follow this [thread](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?167,414694,414694). Go in your configuration manager and change your target platform.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I had already tried changing the platform to x64, and it did not work. I still get the same errors.

Comment: Have you been instructed to use a pre-processor define to set the library as static? Setting or not this define should toggle static or dynamic linkage.

Comment: The instructions I was given with the library told me to add the following to my preprocessors; Am I missing something?
WIN32
_DEBUG
_CONSOLE
HAVE_INT8_T=1
CPPCON_PUBLIC_FUNC=

Comment: Maybe, what I expected to find is not there. After reading your edit, did the assignment come with any DLL, or just headers and lib? Did you install everything that is required?

Comment: It came with a lot of folders and files, but specifically on the library: It came with 4 files. Two .lib files (libmysql.lib and mysqlcppcon-static.lib) which I was told to use. Included are also two .dll files (libmysql.dll and mysqlcppcon.dll) which I wasn't told to use. I carefully went through the steps and there was no mention of any dlls. Besides those there are some sql-related header files.

Comment: You also need to add the lib files in the Linker input additional dependencies, and add the path for them in the additional library directories.

Comment: They have been added into the input additional dependencies since the very start, but additional library directories?